# FsReveal Line Highlighting

Tags: f#, reveal.js, fsreveal

I am trying to highlight lines in an FsReveal presentation. I want to show all the lines then in the next step highlight line 3. I know this is possible in Reveal.js but I am not sure how to use it from FsReveal. Here is what I tried:

````
***
- data-line-number : 1-3|3

### Chicken

```
let x = 10
let y = ["a"; "b"; "c"]
let monkey = 100.0
```

***
````

Instead of showing all the lines and then highlighting the third line on the next right-arrow, it just shows all the lines as normal and moves on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really have a working answer, but I have two thoughts that could help.

First, the `data-line-numbers` attribute needs to be set on the `<code>` element of your snippet. The way you are setting it, it will be copied to the `<section>` element. This is unfortunate, because the `<code>` element is generated from Markdown formatting, so you cannot directly set this. You can still have HTML elements in your markdown document, so you could try if this works:

```
<pre><code class="nohighlight" data-line-numbers="3,8-10">
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Apples</td>
    <td>$1</td>
    <td>7</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Oranges</td>
    <td>$2</td>
    <td>18</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</code></pre>
```

This did not actually work for me, sadly, despite generating what looks like correct HTML. I suspect this is because FsReval uses an older version of reveal.js. There should be a way to update that.

If you got this to work, you could try setting the attribute on the generated `<code>` using JavaScript, right after your HTML element:

````
```
let x = 10
let y = ["a"; "b"; "c"]
let monkey = 100.0
```

<script>
var els = document.getElementsByTagName("code");
els[els.length-1].setAttribute("data-line-numbers","3,8-10");
</script>
````